# Как использовать std::bind с методами класса?

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь использовать `std::bind` с методом класса:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
class Test{
public:
    void print(int a){
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    Test test;
    std::bind(test, test.print, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор выдает следующую ошибку:

> ```
> Reference to non-static member function must be called.
> ```

Как исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прежде, чем писать на все знакомые форумы первым делом лучше почитать документацию - там много полезного написано. Например сигнатура `std::bind`:

```cpp
template< class F, class... Args >
/*unspecified*/ bind( F&& f, Args&&... args );
```

Как видим, первым аргументом должен идти функтор, а у вас, почему-то объект `test`.

Исправим:

```cpp
std::bind(test.print, 5);
```

Однако получаем ошибку при попытке скомпилировать, на этот раз что-то вроде `invalid non-static member function` - это потому что мы не можем вот так обращаться к методам объектам, вместо этого указатель на метод записывается так:

```cpp
std::bind(&Test::print, 5);
```

Однако, как мы видим, мы имеем указатель на метод, но нигде не указываем сам объект - нам компилятор на этот раз сообщит о невалидном количестве параметров в функции. Все потому, что в методах (не статических) всегда есть минимем один аргумент - это this. И хоть он не указывается при определении метода, это тем не менее самый настоящий аргумент.

Как результат в итге получаем:

```cpp
std::bind(&Test::bind, &test, 5);
```

**UDP** Тут в комментах также подсказали, что можно к методу биндить не только указатель, но и ссылку - это абсолютно верно, но есть одно большое НО, о чем автор коммента забыл упомянуть. Давайте разберемся что за но.

```cpp
  std::bind(&Test::print, test, 5);
```

С первого взгляда все ок, все работает как ожидается, но давайте немного усложним класс `Test`. Предположим это объект который содержит сокет и во время вызова `print` пишет что-то в сокет. Сокет такая вещь, которую лучше не копировать, поэтому пометим наш класс как `nocopyable`

```cpp
class Test {
...
Test() = default;
Test(const Test &) = delete;
}
```

И что же мы увидим при попытке компиляции? Ошибку. Компилятор нам сообщит, что не может скопировать объект `test` чтобы использовать его в `std::bind`. Как видим, подобныя ситуация может быть весьма и весьма чревата в реальной ситуации. К счастью она весьма просто исправляется: нужно указать, что мы передаем `test` именно по ссылке

```cpp
std::bind(&Test::print, std::ref(test), 5);
```

Данные момент нужно знать обязательно, так как не зная об этом вы можете провести много времени в дебаге пытаяся разобраться в том, почему изменяя объект вы никак не влияете на результат

Comment: Можно передать и ссылку: и  еще для вызова функции нужно вызвать оператор():        `std::bind(&Test::bind, test, 5)()`

Comment: А если объект test будет обернут в chared_ptr? Тоже самое?

Comment: @DenverToha да без разницы

Comment: Вы знаете как обращаться к объекту через указатель(через умный указатель также)  std::bind(&Test::bind, *smartptr, 5)()

Comment: @ARHovsepyan добавил в ответ